# jquery form validation in popup window

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am developing one application which is in codeigniter with smarty template and in that html pages are ready I have to just develop that pages. In that application there is one page which is open in like lightbox as a form and I want to put jquery validation in that I have trying with

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#frm_email").validate({ 
            rules: {
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email : true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                email: {
                    required:  "Email is required.",
                    email : "Enter valid email."
                }
            },
            // the errorPlacement has to take the table layout into account
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                if ( $(element).is(":radio") ){
                    $(error).insertAfter( $(element).parent() );
                } else if ( $(element).is(":checkbox") ){ 
                    $(error).insertAfter( $(element).next() );
                } else{
                    if($(element).is("textarea")){
                        $(error).insertAfter($(element).next());
                    } else {
                        $(error).insertAfter( $(element) );
                    }
                }               
            },
            success: function(label ) {
                $(label).remove();          
            },
            onkeyup: function(element) { $(element).valid(); },
            onfocusout: function(element) { $(element).valid(); }
        });
    });
 });
```

this code but its not working and I want form validation before form submit.

So please help me.

Comment: are you loading jquery.min.js and jquery.validate.js ?

Comment: yes I am uploading that both js.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jQuery wrapper to make it work:

element should be $(element) and error should be $(error)

```
if ( element.is(":radio") )
                    $(error).insertAfter( $(element).parent() );
                else if ( $(element).is(":checkbox") )
                    $(error).insertAfter( $(element).next() );
                //else{
                    else if($(element).is("textarea"))
                    $(error).insertAfter($(element).next());
                else
                    $(error).insertAfter( $(element) );
                //}
```

Also, I noticed if else condition is wrong, fix that. (You have else condition without if condition :: check properly)

Comment: Hello C-link I have make changes as you told in my script but not working.